# CORS issues even after using npm cors plugin in node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, axios

I have created a simple server in node js to take the request from a react app.

But for the GET method there is no CORS error but whenever I do post, it gives me an error.

[image]

For the POST method to work, I have implemented in index.js file of the actions folder and it should hit the url from the server.js  file.

index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_NAVBAR = "GET_NAVBAR";
export const LOGIN = "LOGIN";

export const BASE_API_URL = "http://localhost:3030";
export const GUEST_API_URL = "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:5443/wcs/resources/store/1";


export const getNavbar = () => {
    return axios.get(BASE_API_URL + '/topCategory').then(res => {
        return {
            type: GET_NAVBAR,
            payload: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        };
    });
};



export const login = () => {
    return axios.post(GUEST_API_URL + '/guestidentity', {}).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return {
            type: LOGIN,
            payload: {}
        }
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        return {
            type: LOGIN,
            payload: {}
        }
    });
};
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;//import it here
const app = express();
const helmet = require('helmet');
const morgan = require('morgan');


// enhance your app security with Helmet
app.use(helmet());

// use bodyParser to parse application/json content-type
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

// log HTTP requests
app.use(morgan('combined'));



app.post('/guestidentity', (req, res) => {

    var client = new Client();

// direct way
    client.post("https://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:5443/wcs/resources/store/1/guestidentity", (data, response) => {
        res.send({express: data});
    });
});



const port = 3030;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

I don't know where my code is getting wrong. Can anybody please help me to troubleshoot this issue. I would be grateful if someone could provide an insight or guide me a little. Thanks

Comment: never expose your IP addresses and ports

Comment: Why are you calling `client.post(` inside the `guestidentity` route in your server? is there a need for calling that api? is that api in a different server? Does this api work with Postman or any other client?

Comment: Yes that is in a different server. Yes it's works with Postman. So what to do now. Will you guide me  a little. In the same server.js file, I m using GET method, but it's working fine. Only for POST, I'm having problem

Answer (score 0):

For my part I used

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

It will accept from any `*` sources, you might want to change that later

Comment: Is my code correct the way I'm hitting from index.js to server.js

Comment: If you are already using the `cors` library you don't need to do this. The library does everything you need, adding the correct headers as well.

Answer (score -1):

In your server.js , add the following middleware.

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3030/');

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');


next();

};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: Do I need to do npm install or just simply add that piece of code.

Comment: just add it. There is no need for anything to be installed.

Comment: but it's not working...Am I hitting the url right from index.js to server.js

Comment: Have you correctly restarted server.js or used nodemon to listen to changes ?

Comment: Yes I have restarted.....but it s showing the cors error. But is my code right the way I m hitting server.js from index.js

Comment: If your GUEST_API_URL is right yes.

Add this to your serv and access it in your browser only with the GUEST_API_URL

`app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.json('You did it, the express server works');
});`

Comment: cors() middleware is already added and hence no need of adding this code, cors will take care of headers and all.